# Suppose $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z^2+t^2=9$ and $xt+yz=6$. What are $x,y,z,t$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z^2+t^2=9$ and $xt+yz=6$.

What are $x,y,z,t$?

Comment: Hint : Equality in the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Different hint parametric equation

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please more guide.

Comment: A single solution can be easily found, e.g. (x,y,z,t) = (0,2,3,0). Do you want all solutions? All integer solutions? All complex solutions?

Comment: With three equations and four unknowns, it seems unlikely that the solution over complex numbers will be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
(x^2+y^2)(z^2+t^2)-(xt+yz)^2=0
$$
Expanding the left-hand side you get
$$
x^2z^2+\color{red}{y^2z^2}+\color{red}{x^2t^2}+y^2t^2
-\color{red}{x^2t^2}-2xyzt-\color{red}{y^2z^2}=0
$$
that simplifies to
$$
(xz-yt)^2=0
$$
so $xz=yt$.

Now consider the linear system in the unknowns $z$ and $t$:
\begin{cases}
yz+xt=6 \\
xz-yt=0
\end{cases}
With standard methods you get
$$
z=\frac{6y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3}{2}y,
\qquad
t=\frac{6x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3}{2}x
$$
Now any pair of numbers $x,y$ with $x^2+y^2=4$ will do.

---

Alternatively, consider the complex numbers
$$
A=x+yi,\qquad B=z+ti
$$
Then the hypotheses yield $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$ and that the imaginary part of $AB$ is $6$, that is
$$
AB=C+6i
$$
with $C$ real. Then $\bar{A}\bar{B}=C-6i$ and multiplying gives
$$
A\bar{A}B\bar{B}=C^2+36
$$
Thus $36=C^2+36$ and so $C=0$. Therefore
$$
AB=6i
$$
and
$$
z+ti=\frac{6i}{x+yi}=\frac{6i}{x-yi}{4}=\frac{3}{2}i(x-yi)=\frac{3}{2}(y+xi)
$$
whence again $z=\frac{3}{2}y$ and $t=\frac{3}{2}x$.

Comment: +1, The first part is of course essentially a proof of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality mentioned by @астон.

Comment: @lhf Yes, of course; OTOH, I don't think an [tag:algebra-precalculus] question can rely on CS.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, this should be solved over $\Bbb R$.

In this case the easiest way to think about this is that you have two (real) vectors $v = (x,y)$ and $w = (t,z)$.

Then,

$$\|v\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt 4 = 2,$$
$$\|w\| = \sqrt{t^2+z^2} = \sqrt 9 = 3,$$
$$v\cdot w = xt + yz = 6.$$

If we denote with $\varphi$ the angle between $v$ and $w$, we have
$$\cos\varphi =\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\|\|w\|} = 1\implies \varphi = 0\implies w =\lambda v,\ \lambda>0.$$

Since $\|w\| = \lambda\| v\|$, we conclude that $\lambda = \frac 32$.

Considering polar coordinates, we can write $v = r(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, $w = \frac 32 r(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, where $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$. Note that $$\|v\| =r\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha + \sin^2\alpha} = r\implies r = 2,$$ meaning that $v = 2(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, $w = 3(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, or

\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{align}
x &= 2\cos\alpha,\\
y &= 2\sin\alpha,\\
t &= 3\cos\alpha,\\
z &= 3\sin\alpha.
\end{align}&\tag{1}\end{array}

Returning to the original system we get

$$x^2+y^2 = 4\cos^2\alpha+4\sin^2\alpha = 4,$$
$$t^2+z^2 = 9\cos^2\alpha+9\sin^2\alpha = 9,$$
$$xt+yz = 6\cos^2\alpha + 6\sin^2\alpha = 6,$$

and thus, all (real) solutions are given by $(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Putting the parametric equation for both circles
$$x=2\sin a,y=2\cos a,z=3\sin b,t=3\cos b\\$$From this you get$$xt-yz=6\sin a\cos b+6\sin b\cos a=6\sin(a+b)=6\\\sin(a+b)=1\\a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k
\pi$$
Which implies $x=2\sin(\pi/2-b)=2\cos b$ and $y=2\cos(\pi/2-b)=2\sin b$
From this we see that $(x,y,z,t)=(2\cos b,2\sin b,3\sin b,3\cos b)$ for each $b$